# Keep navbar at top of page when scrolled to correct position

Tags: javascript, html, css

So with my website I have a header. At the top of the header I have my logo and slogan, and beneath that I have my nav bar. When the user scrolls down I want the top part of the header (logo and slogan) to disappear  whereas the nav bar should stay fixed. I know this would need some `position:fixed;` added to it but how do I get it to activate only when it's in the right place. I've worked a bit with media queries before. Is there one for a y-scroll?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use javascript here in order to subscribe for `window.onscroll` event.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset > 100/*px*/)
        $('.nav').addClass('fixed_bar');
    else
        $('.nav').removeClass('fixed_bar');
}
```

And css for `.fixed_bar` will be something like this:

```
.fixed_bar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:10000;
}
.fixed_bar .logo{
    display:none;
}
```

Also, you'll have to account for a space that the fixed nav will free and add `padding` or `margin` to the beneath element;

Comment: Is your syntax correct? It didn't work for me initially. I then went back and adjusted it to this window.onscroll = function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset > 210/*px*/) {
        $('.bottom_header').addClass('fixed_bar');
  $('.top_header').css('visibility:hidden;');
 }
 else /*if(window.pageYOffset <= 210 /*px)*/ { 
  $('.bottom_header').removeClass('fixed_bar'); 
  $('.top_header').css('visibility:visible;'); 
 }
}

Comment: But thanks anyway, I didn't know about the window.pageYOffset bit before :)

Comment: Yeah, the syntax is correct, but the classes I used in the example were not actual and given as an example only. Your adjusted code looks good. The /*px*/ comment is not necessary, I added it for visual transparency only.

Comment: Yeah I knew that. Hm strange how it only works with the extra curley braces after if and else though.